# Can't use django variable in include tag

Tags: django

I'm trying to include a .html using

```
{% include "paintings/experiments/points/{{substance.name}}.html" %}
```

This however leads to the error `TemplateDoesNotExist`.

If I hardcode the name of the .html file, it does work.

```
{% include "paintings/experiments/points/fabric.html" %}
```

And, in fact, I can use `{{substance.name}}` inside the included html, were it does indeed get substituted for `fabric`. Why can I not use a django variable when using an include tag?

Comment: Because it wasn't made to be used like that. The template name can be either a string or a variable, not both at the same time.

Comment: See the duplicate answer. In your case, you need to use the `add:` filter twice, e.g. `"paintings/experiments/points/"|add:substance.name|add:".html"`. You might find the code cleaner if you set `include_template_name = "paintings/experiments/points/%s.html" % substance.name` in the view, then use `{% include include_template_name %}` in the template.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you. I was searching specifically for the include tag, now it makes sense why I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Alasdair. It appears not work.  using `{% include "paintings/experiments/points/"|add:substance.name|add:".htm‌​l" %}
` returns `UnicodeEncodeError at /mturk/external/task/120/
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 132-133: ordinal not in range(128)`. Which is strange, since the line isn't even 133 characters long.

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell what the problem is from that error message.

Comment: @Alasdair Turns out that there's a non-visble non-ASCII character in your comment at ".htm‌​l" between the m and l.

Comment: I've had an answer with the use of [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags), but then this question was closed. Since `include` tag accepts variable, you can create variable inside template with a custom template tag and then use this newly created variable in the `include`. E.g. `build_template_path(base, name): return base.format(name)` and in the template `{% build_template_path 'paintings/experiments/points/{}.html' substance.name as template_path %}` and then `{% include template_path %}`.

Comment: That’s bizarre, don’t know how the non breaking space crept in. Unfortunately I can’t edit it since the comment is more than 5 minutes old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doit with the `add` templateTag.

```
{% include "paintings/experiments/points/"|add:substance.name %}
```

Notice that `substance.name` should have `.html` . I'm using this approach to use dynamic Templates. So in a `context_processor` I set the variable value and use it normally, like this:

```
{% include ""|add:paginationTemplatePath with page=page_obj %}
```

In this case, I change the `paginationTemplatePath` given certain conditions on the `context_processor`.
I'm exposing this example in order to enrich the answer for other cases, as use include with variable `page`.

Answer (score 1):

`include` template tag was designed to accept either string or variable. If you try to use the above, it's just going to be string. But you can manipulate strings with template filters and tags.

You can create custom template tag that creates variable and then use that newly created variable in the `include` tag. If you check the documentation on [Custom template tags and filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) you'll see how they work and what are the requirements for them to work.

First you must create a directory inside your app named `templatetags`

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        custom_tags.py
    views.py
```

Below is a possible code to create variable for template path:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def build_template_path(base, name):
    return base.format(name)
```

`base` in your case would be `"paintings/experiments/points/{}.html"` and `name` would be `source.name`.

Now in the template you first have to load these custom tags with:

```
{% load custom_tags %}
```

and then you use this template tag in the template:

```
{% for source in sources %}
    {% build_template_path "paintings/experiments/points/{}.html" source.name as template_path %}
    {% include template_path %}
{% endfor %}
```

With `build_template_path` you create custom variable `template_path` which you then use in the `include` tag.

Overall, template tags are very powerful. You can create or do pretty much anything with them, while filters are a bit more limited, but you could have done that with filters as well. Maybe something like this:

```
@register.filter
def replace_value(value, name):
    return value.replace('**', name)

{% include "paintings/experiments/points/**.html"|replace_value:source.name %}
```